# Teamcity equivalent of Jenkins DSL or Jenkins Job Builder?

Tags: jenkins, automation, continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm looking for a way to configure TeamCity jobs using readable text files.

Jenkins have things like [Jenkins Job Builder](http://ci.openstack.org/jenkins-job-builder/) and the upcoming [DSL plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin), but I haven't found something like this for TeamCity.

The purpose of this is to enable scriptable, repeatable job configuration.

Is anyone aware of something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now a native feature of TeamCity 10. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Kotlin+DSL

You should also check out the TeamCity2DSL from jonnyzzz. He covers an example workflow in this post. http://jonnyzzz.com/blog/2016/03/08/gradle-for-dsl/

It is described as " Refactor TeamCity configuration XML files via Kotlin DSL " and the repository is here. https://github.com/jonnyzzz/TeamCity2DSL

I'm curious whether the TeamCity2DSL is compatible with the TeamCity 10 DSL, but I haven't had a chance to test yet.

Comment: Thanks very much for the pointer. It looks promising. I've since moved to another workplace which doesn't use TeamCity but stashed this project in my toolbox.